# Help with Product Import on Magento 1.9 to 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, delta-migration

We are in the process of migrating a site from Magento 1.9.3.1 to 2.2.3. This site has over 11k products, 25k orders.

We used the official Magento migration tool but were unsuccessful since the product details were shuffled, in the sense, the description was in the title, the pricing was in the description, etc.

Post that we used a third party tool called https://www.ubertheme.com/question/magento2_data_migration-master-zip/.

With this tool, we were able to import the products and everything seems alright in the backend (admin panel) but on the frontend (the theme) none of the products get listed. We reverted the theme to the default Magento theme and the issue continued to persist.

This is where we are stuck at this point.

We have followed several other instructions from different blogs to fix this issue. These are the steps failed

- Reindexed the database
- Used DI compile command for the catalog module
- deleted cache files and used static content deploy, Used Magento
  upgrade command
- re-setting value of Stores/Configuration/Catalog/Inventory/Stock
  Options/Display Out of Stock Products to ‘Yes’
- Rechecked the products have visibility on the main website and made
  sure they are enabled
- updated the customer_group_id in the customer_group table for NOT
  LOGGED IN USER to 0
- updated vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/Readhandler.php
  to the latest git version

The current theory that we have is that  there is a problem with either EAV table group migration or
minor changes in any tables causing catalog->category->product relationship.

We would very much appreciate insights/help/ help at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for it at last.

While working with the official Magento migration tool,

We need to configure the map.xml file for relating the source and destination tables and differences in the table structure like new fields, data structure differences etc.. 
Once you done that properly, there won't be any data shuffle and the data will be migrated perfectly.